# How to create an AngularJS directive that binds to a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to build a directive for showing datepicker textboxes, i.e regular textboxes which have JQuery UI's datepicker used on them, so when the user clicks them, a datepicker box opens to let them pick the date, etc.

I want to bind this directive somehow to a property on my scope. E.g if it were a normal textbox and I did `ng-model='myDate'` then `$scope.myDate` would be updated if the user typed in a new date. In the same way, I want to bind this field from the directive so when the user picks a date, it updates the scope property its bound to.

The problem is, I want to display the directive using something like this:

```
<datepicker name='something' value='2013-07-20' model='myProperty' />
```

And have the directive replace it with the `<input type="text" />` etc. So I can't use `ng-model`.

How else can I bind the `model` property to the directive so that it updates whenever the user changes it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this is what you want:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <foo model="property"></foo>
    <input type="text" ng-model="property">
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .directive('foo', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            scope: { model: '=' },
            template: '<input type="text" ng-model="model">'        
        };
    })
    .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
       $scope.property = 'Foobar'; 
    });
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j6Zaa/3/)

In order to use `ng-model` instead of `model`, you'll need to wrap the input in a container tag. Here's another [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j6Zaa/4/) script that illustrates it.

Finally, there's a date picker control in [Angular UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). Perhaps it already does what you need.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `scope{value: '='}` and then in the html: `<datepicker value='dateProperty'>`?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't picked good names. I'll update the code so it's less ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks. I built the directive using your answer as help, but I'm running into another issue. If you might be able to help here, I'd appreciate it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139375/how-to-update-an-angularjs-directive-when-a-scope-variable-is-updated-via-ajax