# scope.$watch in a directive isn't being called after AJAX request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following directive:

```
MyApp.directive('myFilter', ['$filter','$rootScope',
function($filter, $rootScope)
{
    var dir = {};
    dir.restrict = 'E';
    dir.templateUrl = 'views/myFilter.html';
    dir.replace = true;
    dir.scope = 
        {
            name: '@',
            model: '=',
        };

    dir.link = function(scope,el,attrs)
    {        
        //stuff here
    }


    return dir; 
}]);
```

Here's how I invoke it:

```
<my-filter model="someField" name="abcd" />
```

When the directive is first initalized, the `someField` is empty. Later on, it is retrieved via ajax, and its value is filled in.

Question is, how can I watch for the value of `someField` to be updated? When I do this from the link method:

```
scope.$watch(scope.model, function()
{
   console.log( "changed, new val: ", scope.model );
}
```

This is only called once, when initalizing the directive, and the value then is empty. When the value is retrieved via ajax (from `$http.get`), this watch function is not called again. However, in other parts of the page where I'm displaying `{{someField}}`, that value DOES update when ajax request is fetched. So I don't think the problem has to do with doing `$scope.apply()` after ajax request.

**Edit:** `someField` is assigned in the controller. Here is the code:

```
MyApp.controller('myCtrl', 
['$scope', '$rootScope', '$routeParams', 
'ajax', '$filter',

function($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams, ajax, $filter)
{
    var userId = parseInt( $routeParams.userId );        
    $scope.loaded = false;
    $scope.someField = ""; //initalize with empty value

    var load = function(data)
    {
        $scope.loaded = true;
        $scope.someField = data.someField;            
    };        

    ajax.getUser(userId).success(load);               
}
]);
```

The method `ajax.getUser()` does a `$http.get()` and returns its `promise`. In the code above, the `load` method is called which sets the value of `someField`.

Comment: Show us how someField is defined, and how retrieved value is assigned to it

Answer (score 92, accepted):

`$watch` expects an expression that can be either a function or a string. So, it'll work if you change it to

```
scope.$watch('model', function() { ... });
```

or

```
scope.$watch(function() { return scope.model; }, function() { ... });
```

Check out [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CSCT6/).

Comment: I believe SO is the best place to discuss things like this, small or not. You can pick everybody's brain, not just mine. :)

Comment: That's true, but AngularJS questions often take a long time to get answered on SO.

Comment: @ClickUpvote: the purpose of a system like SO is for the entire community to benefit.  You're asking Michael to be your private consultant.  Back in Usenet days, we didn't answer by email for this reason.

Comment: @DuncanBayne Point taken. :)

Comment: what is `prop` being passed in (fiddle)?

Comment: @chovy It's simply a property of the scope. It was used so the directive could communicate back with the (implicit) controller.

Comment: If you applied this directive to many elements, wouldn't it keep applying watches on the same elements?