# When do we need to manually watch scope variable and when not in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

All:

I am new to AngularJS directive, I got a question about monitoring scope variable which is:

I want to know when I should manually add scope.$watch, for example: I build a directive like

```
        app.directive("followerlist", function(){
            return {
                restrict: "AE",
                scope: {
                    fllws: "="
                },
                templateUrl: "tmpl/followerlist.html",
                controller: function(){

                },
                link: function(scope, EL, attrs){

                }
            }
        });
```

The template is like:

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="f in fllws">
    {{f.login}}
</li>
</ul>
```

And the html is like:

```
<body ng-controller="main">
    <followerlist fllws="followers"></followerlist>
</body>
```

In this way, I do not need to manually register any watcher but still can respond to the data change (if I change $scope.followers in main controller, the list can change immediately )

I thought I should manually watch the change for external and internal variable(sometime the change will not get respond unless I manually register watcher), I wonder if anyone could give me some summary about when I should manually watch and when I do not need to?

Thanks

Comment: For objects and arrays,  generally you don't need to watch unless changes to that array/object may have an impact on other models in the scope. As long as angular is aware of the changes, the view should update by internal watchers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works without manually creating a watch because Angular did that for you when you bound the `fllws` property to your template. Angular automatically does that for every binding unless you use a [one-time binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding).

You should manually create a watch every time you need to perform some action when the model changes or a condition becomes true. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139375/angularjs-scope-watch-in-a-directive-isnt-being-called-after-ajax-request/18139617#18139617) contains more technical information about it.

Comment: Thanks, so I only need to care about the scope variable that not used in template. But I wonder why I do not need to watch a service data change?  For example, I inject a service in, and that service has a data array(like dataservice.data), I give that whole array to scope.data = dataservice.data, whenever I change member inside service.data(but not change the whole array), the scope.data can get auto updated, could you tell how angular find that change(does that mean all watch in template is a deepWatch to reference object)?